# Why is r10k called r10k?

Tags: puppet, r10k

I am using r10k for a while now. I wonder what r10k means.

**Questions**

Why is the tool called r10k? Where does it stand for?

**Attempts to answer the question**

Neither the [puppet docs](https://docs.puppet.com/pe/latest/r10k.html), nor the internet indicates where r10k stands for

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because what does this have to do with anything?

Comment: it will save time in future whenever someone new to server admin using Puppet and R10K comes along and asks "what the heck doe R10K mean?" and waist half an hour in a fruitless attempt at finding a sensible answer.  There is no sensible answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Neither the puppet docs, nor the internet indicates where r10k stands for

Well, it's explained [over here](https://github.com/puppetlabs/r10k/blob/main/doc/faq.mkd#what-does-the-name-mean):

> It’s called R10K because I’m terrible at names. When I started working on R10K I couldn’t come up with a decent name. While trying to come up with something clever, I recalled that Randall Munroe wrote a bot for controlling IRC chatter, and gave it the most generic name he could think of - Robot 9000. Since I just needed a name, any name, I decided to go with an equally generic name by incrementing the robot index.